# How to offer Views as options in a Content-Type field

Tags: 7, views, entities, nodes

I would like to add a field to a content type (Events) that gives several views (Certificates of Completion) as options.  Thus, when creating an Event the admin can select which certificate will be associated with this Event.

I'm hoping there is a module for this, but as you might imagine Google can't figure out exactly what I'm asking when my query is predominantly filled with generic drupal terms like "Content Type", "Field", and "Views".

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a taxonomy for that content type and assign values to it like "Certificates of Completion", etc. Here is the [Link](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy) for the taxonomy docs.

Comment: I currently have a View with one display per certificate.  Each display has a different background image and different coordinates for where the date and attendee's name should appear.  If I use a Taxonomy for the certificates then I face the same problem.  How to I translate from "Content-Type has Taxonomy" to "use this View Display"?  Which is basically the original problem, how to use a Content-Type Field to select a View Display.  It just shifts from Content-Type Field to Taxonomy, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The closer module I can think of is the [View reference](http://drupal.org/project/viewreference) module.

> Defines a field type View reference which creates a relationship to a Views display and allows the view to be displayed as the content of the field.
>
> This module is modeled on the Node reference module, and usage is similar.
>
> Additionally, you may enter arguments for each view by a delimiter separated list with support for PHP generated arguments.